# WPF. Максимальный размер текста в Label

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Нужна помощь. Как узнать, какой размер шрифта (свойство FontSize) в Label будет максимальным для полного отображения (без каких-либо обрезаний букв снизу или сверху) при изменении размеров окна?

Comment: Можно попробовать вычислить: 1 кегль = 1/72 дюйма. Можно взять TextBlock и поместить его во ViewBox и растянуть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поместите ваш TextBlock во ViewBox, главное выберите векторный шрифт:

```
<Viewbox>
    <TextBlock Text="Some text"/>
</Viewbox>
```

[Посмотреть gif (1,5 МБ)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsTxi.gif)